# Mqtt: is it necessary to unsubscribe?

Tags: mqtt

If a client is disconnecting, is it necessary to unsubscribe beforehand?

I originally thought it was, but then if a client disconnects unexpectedly, you cannot unsubscribe ..

therefore, unsubscribing is pointless unless you are still connected and no longer want to receive messages ..

Is this a correct assumption?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have connected with the `clean session` flag set to 1 then when you disconnect the broker will remove all of your subscriptions and other information.

If `clean session` was set to 0 when you connected, then your subscriptions are saved at the broker until you unsubscribe (or reconnect with `clean session` set to 1 at a later point)

Comment: ... and if you used a clean session false/0 and you re-subscribe it won't cause an error it will be a no-op ?

Comment: If you resubscribe you will get the retained messages again, but otherwise will cause no error.